# Writing each json message to unique file with NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I want to log each json message received from the network into a unique file.

At first I thought to do `File.WriteAllText($"{Guid.NewGuid()}.json", jsonMsg);`. But, I need to be able to archive and delete old log files. So, I have to watch the folder when the application starts up and do all the things that NLog already knows how to do.

With NLog, I can create and add a new `Target` for each message from code. But I'm not sure how to remove those targets after the message has been written. Otherwise, it will create memory leak.

So, should I just stick with my first idea and just implement the logic to archive and delete files, or is there a way to do this with NLog?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a single filetarget for doing the writing, but avoid using `MaxArchiveFiles` for archive-cleanup:

```cs
var myguid = Guid.NewGuid();
var logEvent = NLog.LogEventInfo.Create(NLog.LogLevel.Info, null, jsonMsg);
logEvent.Properties["msguid"] = myguid;
logger.Log(logEvent);
```

And then use [${event-properties}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) in the FileName-option:

```xml
<target type="file" name="fileNetworkMessages"
        fileName="messages/Archive/Output-${event-properties:myguid}.json"
        layout="${message}" keepFileOpen="false" />
```

When including Guid in the filename, then you should avoid using `MaxArchiveFiles`, because it will introduce a performance-hit for every new file created, and cleanup will not work (HEX-letters will disturb file-wildcard).

NLog FileTarget `MaxArchiveFiles` has an overhead when rolling to a new file, where it scans all existing files to see if cleanup is necessary. This works fine when only rolling once every hour/day. But when using Guid in the filename, then NLog FileTarget will trigger a cleanup-check for every new file created. This will introduce a performance overhead.

Comment: This doesn't archive old files. I even tried this but I don't know what should be for `archiveFileName` since it always changes    
`<target type="file"
        name="fileNetworkMessages"
        filename="messages/${event-properties:msguid}.json"
        layout="${message}"
        archiveFileName="messages/Archive/WHAT_SHOULD_BE_HERE.json2"
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
        archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
            />`

Comment: NLog v4.5 improved [dynamic-archive-mode](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files) just remove `archiveFileName="..."` and `archiveNumbering="..."` and `archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"` (As shown in my example). It is important to [Not mix dynamic- and static-archive-mode](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic)

Comment: I'm using NLog v5.1.1. I tried your example, but it just addes new files and never archives them

Comment: The idea with dynamic-archive-mode is that you never "move the files", but just writes directly to the intended directory. The archive-cleanup will then monitor that directory using file-wildcard `Output*.json`. Have updated my example again to reflect that.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I used your `target` configuration and ran your code example in a loop that logged 200 messages. It never deleted any files over 100. It just added 200 json files and that's it. I even stopped the application and started it again. It never deleted any old files. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes sorry about the confusion. My brain forgot about HEX-values in Guid, and the archive-cleanup-wildcard gets confused by the letters `abcdef`. Would it work if we convert to digits-only ?

Comment: @theateist Think it could be nice if NLog was able to recognize Guid-output, so one didn't need special logic. But to avoid matching issues would it be acceptable that NLog only recongized `Guid.ToString("D")`. Ex. `12345678-1234-1234-1234-abc123456789` (As the `-`-delimeters will reduce false positives)

Comment: @theateist After looking at the NLog FileTarget Archive-Logic, then I think you should only use NLog FileTarget for writing the guid-files. But find a different solution for doing periodic-cleanup, since NLog FileTarget archive-cleanup introduces an overhead that is triggered for every new file.

Comment: Depending on your frequency you should either replace the guid with a timestamp or just include a timestamp with a specific sortable format (eg. `yyyyMMdd-hhmm-ss`). If you use this timestamp _early_ in the filename you can easily sort the directory by name and delete old logs. Another approach would be to use the different parts of the timestamp for a folder structure (eg. `/{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/{mm}/{ss.fff}{Guid.NewGuid()}.log`). In that case you can simply delete specific folders when needed.